# Explicit formula of a recursively defined sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there an explicit formula for this sequence?

$a_1=2$

$a_{n+1}=(a_n)^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. We have

$$a_{n+1} = (a_n)^2 = (a_{n-1})^{2^2} = (a_{n-2})^{2^3} = \cdots = (a_1)^{2^n} = 2^{2^n}$$

So $a_n = 2^{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: a rare example when squared/nonlinear sequences have a closed-form solution, (+1)

Comment: @Alex Except for all other sequences of the form $a_{n+1}=f^{-1}(f(a_n)+1)$.

Comment: According to this answer, $a_2$ would be 16, which doesn't match the recurrence.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: like $\sqrt{a^2_k +1}$?

Comment: @Alex Yes, like $a_{k+1}=\sqrt{a_k^2+1}$.

Comment: And how is this recurrence solved?

Comment: @Alex you can argue inductively.

Comment: @Alex  $a_n = \sqrt{a_1^2+n-1}$. And the example here corresponds to $f(x)=\log_2\log_2 x$. Anyway, with this lovely conversation I almost forgot to downvote + vote to close.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: could you mb point to some book where advanced recurrence problems are discussed?

Comment: @Alex That could be a [book-recommendation] question. But there is nothing advanced in what I wrote: take the trivial recurrence $a_{n+1}=a_n+1$ and conjugate it by some function $f$.

Comment: Why the downvote?